# how to get edge of image MATLAB image processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing

how to get edge of image? i wanna code matlab

Image description:
[image]
<sub>(source: [free.in.th](http://image.free.in.th/z/if/6lena.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably add more details, but if you want the outside of an image, try something like:

```
im1 = imread('Your_Image_Filename.jpg');
EdgeWidth = 5; % How many pixels at edge of image you want
if (2*EdgeWidth > size(im1,1) || 2*EdgeWidth > size(im1,2))
    error('Image smaller than edge width selected');
end

im1(EdgeWidth+1:(end-EdgeWidth),(EdgeWidth+1:(end-EdgeWidth)),:)=255;
```

Comment: sorry Error: File: test55.m Line: 3 Column: 1
At least one END is missing: the statement may begin here.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the "end" for the "if".

Comment: you can see image description . i want margin of an image

Comment: What output do you want as data? An image with white in the middle and only the margins unchanged?

Comment: yes i want white in the middle and image in border

Comment: Edited code does this. Not sure why you are using matlab for this.

Comment: if i want middle to clear .  you can do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, try using Matlabs edge() function.
The canny method is still one of the best known methods.

```
I = imread('lena.jpg');
BW = edge(I,'canny');
```